# Mongoose User, Roles & Permissions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm pretty new to NoSQL/Mongo/Mongoose and I'm trying to determine the best way of setting up the schemas. Here's what I have:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      select: false,
    },
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Role',
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

```js
const RoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
    permissions: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Permission',
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

```js
const PermissionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
  }
);
```

Straightforward enough, the User has Roles and Roles have Permissions.

If I wanted to find a user and their permissions, should this be done via **populate** somehow even though the permissions aren't actually directly part of the User schema, or should/could this be a **virtual**?

Essentially, what I want to be able to do is access the user's permissions something like this:

```js
const user = User.findById(id);
console.log(user.permissions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve permissions of a user in one query you can use **nested population**.

Here is the code:

```js
User.findById(id)
    .populate({
        path: 'roles',
        populate: [{
          path: 'permissions',
          model: 'Permission'
    }]
}).exec();
```

If you want to read more about mongoose population see [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can confirm that this method does populate the permissions.